# Equivalence in equals method

Tags: java, equals

Why not `Integer.valueOf(42).equals(Long.valueOf(42))` ?
Whether implementation of `equals` must be "reflexive, symmetric, transitive, consistent"
but don`t have to be reasonable? :)

Comment: Can you give us some context to your question? What are you talking about?

Comment: They're not the same type, so they don't match as equal. How would the Integer object know about all the various numeric types that might be implemented and code for them. That would be unreasonable.

Comment: @DonBranson Except, `Long` has a `intValue()` method it could use, just like any of the other `Number` classes.

Comment: Hmm, I'd say the designers of Java got this one wrong (this is far too similar to the last conversation Sotirios and I had).  I would expect that any Number that's equal to 42 should be `equals` to any other Number that's equal to 42, regardless of their type.  However, it's the sort of thing that they can't go back and fix "after the fact".  Correcting this behaviour might break stuff.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - But what about the numeric types you write? I guess they could all implement some interface. As the number of types grow, either approach creates a huge burden to handle all the different types.

Comment: @DonBranson I'm not saying they should, but that it is possible. The `Number` class is the parent class of all the general numeric types in Java, `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, etc., but also `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`. They must all therefore implement the `abstract intValue()` method. It is available. `Integer` _could_ have used it.

Comment: @DavidWallace - equal as what type? `int`? Then `Long.valueOf((Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L) << 1) + 42)` would also equal `Integer.valueOf(42)`. Equal as a `long`? Then what about `Long.valueOf(42).equals(Double.valueOf(42.1))`? What about `BigDecimal` numbers? What about a `Number` class that isn't part of the standard API?

Comment: Yeah, it might be possible to find a good solution for integers, but I shudder to think about what it means for a `double` to be equal to a `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs for [`Integer.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not `null` and is an `Integer` object that contains the same `int` value as this object.

In other words, an `Integer` will never test as `equals()` to a `Long` (or anything else that's not an `Integer`), regardless of the value being represented. Just compare the primitive values if that's what you're after.

One good reason for not allowing cross-class comparisons is: how would you do it? Suppose you decided to implement `Integer.equals()` to test whether the other object was an instance of `Number` and compare values using `other.intValue()` (which all `Number` classes support). The unfortunate result would be that

```
Integer.valueOf(42).equals(Long.valueOf(((Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L) << 1) + 42))
```

would test `true` because `Long.intValue()` simply casts its value to an `int` and

```
(int) ((Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L) << 1) + 42)
```

evaluates to 42 because that's what's in the lower 32 bits. What's perhaps even worse, if you used the same logic for `Long.equals()` (where it tested all `Number` objects used `longValue()`), then the `equals()` test would no longer be symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

A reminder that `Integer` and `Long` are object wrapper classes of the primitive types `int` and `long`.

Here is the source code of the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method in `Integer` (`value` here is an `int` primitive).

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here is the source code of the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method in `Long` (`value` here is a `long` primitive).

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Long) {
        return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

From the source, the `equals` method firstly checks if the passed-in `obj` is an instance of the corresponding class. If it isn't, `equals` skips the check on the primitive `value` and returns `false`.

So as @Ted Hopp suggested, an `Integer` will never test as equal to a `Long` (or anything else that's not an `Integer`). Comparing primitive values is recommended.

If you nonetheless would like to carry out the equivalence check in the object wrapper setting, then you may wish to widen your Integer (avoiding an overflow) and let the Java compiler do some [auto-(un)boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for you. Something like...

```java
Long theLong = Long.valueOf(42);
Integer theInteger = Integer.valueOf(42);
Long theIntegerInLong = (long) theInteger;
System.out.println(theLong.equals(theIntegerInLong) ? "Equal" : "Unequal");
```

Answer (score -1):

.equals() is for comparisons between objects in the same inheritance hierarchy, up to and including the ultimate superclass Object.  While classes Integer and Long both inherit from java.lang.Number, class Number is apparently missing an .equals() method that compares a Number instance value.  Integer and Long's only shared .equals() method is in Object.  The Object-to-Object comparison method does not evaluate based on the values of the numbers, hence the seemingly strange result printed.

The documentation for class Integer says:
.equals(): "The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is an Integer object that contains the same int value as this object."  It doesn't handle Long values as more than Objects.

Apparently as per @David_Wallace, other class hierarchies implement .equals() in their superclass.  new ArrayList().equals(new LinkedList()) returns true, and both inherit from class java.util.AbstractList which has its own implementation of .equals()

Answer (score -1):

It would have been possible to define the equality tests among wrapper classes in such a fashion that two wrapper objects that encapsulated the same numerical value would compare equal, regardless of the underlying type.  Doing so, however, requires either having all types whose instances may compare equal know about each other, or else requires defining a means via which objects will be able to compare themselves to other objects which haven't even been invented yet.  Taking the former approach would mean that even if a new numeric type was capable of representing the value 5, an `Integer` which equaled 5 could not report itself equal to an instance of the new type which also represented 5.  Taking the latter approach would allow the new object to compare equal to an `Integer` with value 5, but would require adding enormous complexity for comparatively little benefit.

Suppose, for example, that one has defined both a `BigDecimal` and a `BigRational` class; the former stores numbers as a `BigInteger` along with a power-of-ten scaling factor; the latter stores a pair of `BigInteger` values which represent a reduced-form fraction.  One could specify that all numeric values which represent rational numbers should be compared by converting them to `BigRational` and comparing the results.  Since every rational number would have a unique representation, such a defined method of comparison would behave as an equivalence relation.  Unfortunately, it would be horrendously slow.  In most cases, it would make more sense to convert comparands into some other form, but trying to identify the best common form for arbitrarily combinations of types would be difficult.  It's much easier to simply say being of different types is sufficient justification for the objects to be called "different".